Why does Go's escape analysis move a variable to the heap even when inlining is applied?
Given this:
package main

func main() {
    _ = f()
}

func f() *int {
    y := 2
    res := y * 2
    return &res
}

If you run:
go build -gcflags '-m'

To get the escape analysis, it says this:
./main.go:7:6: can inline f
./main.go:3:6: can inline main
./main.go:4:7: inlining call to f
./main.go:9:2: moved to heap: res

Cool. Inlines f(), makes sense, but then it says it moves res to the heap. Idk why it would still go to the heap if it inlines it, and if you benchmark this func this is what you get:
func Benchmark(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        _ = f()
    }
}

Benchmark-10        1000000000           0.3179 ns/op          0 B/op          0 allocs/op

No allocations.... so how is it being moved to the heap?
Then if I specifically tell it to not inline:
package main

func main() {
    _ = f()
}

//go:noinline
func f() *int {
    y := 2
    res := y * 2
    return &res
}

Then rerun the build with escape analysis I get this:
./main.go:3:6: can inline main
./main.go:10:2: moved to heap: res

This makes sense that it is moved to the heap. And now the benchmark says this:
Benchmark-10        136416090            8.620 ns/op           8 B/op          1 allocs/op

So I'm just curious why, in the first example, it is saying it is allocating it to the heap but the benchmark is not showing that it is?

This is an implementation detail of the compiler and may change whenever someone implements it or will stay that way if nobody thinks it’s worth the effort. Typically there are no fundamental reasons or deep hidden knowledge to discover here but simply no one thought it would be worth working on that.

9:2: moved to heap: res is a function f code analysis message. In some places the function f code may be inlined, in other places the code may not be inlined. If f is not inlined then res is allocated on the heap. In this place, 4:7: inlining call to f, the function f code is inlined and no allocation occurs.

The Go gcc compiler is an optimizing compiler. The main function has no effect; all results are discarded. The main function is optimized away by reducing it to a single amd64 assembler instruction: RET.

The Go gcc compiler is an optimizing compiler. The Benchmark function call  _ = f() has no effect; the result is discarded. The function call is optimized away. Benchmark measures the time taken to loop b.N (1_000_000_000) times. In amd64 assembler, the loop is: INCQ, CMPQ and JG.

Ah ok this makes sense now. Thanks!

I believe it just optimized by the compiler, you could see what really happen by looking into the assembly code.
Env:
go version go1.22.3 linux/amd64

With inline:
the compiler is smart enough to skip 'useless' work, so there is not allocs.
000000000045d120 <main.main>:
  45d120:       c3                      retq
  45d121:       cc                      int3
  45d122:       cc                      int3
  45d123:       cc                      int3
  45d124:       cc                      int3
  45d125:       cc                      int3
  45d126:       cc                      int3
  45d127:       cc                      int3
  45d128:       cc                      int3
  45d129:       cc                      int3
  45d12a:       cc                      int3
  45d12b:       cc                      int3
  45d12c:       cc                      int3
  45d12d:       cc                      int3
  45d12e:       cc                      int3
  45d12f:       cc                      int3

Without inlining:
main.main will have to call main.f, then we can find runtime.newobject, which is allocing memory on the heap.
000000000045d120 <main.main>:
  45d120:       49 3b 66 10             cmp    0x10(%r14),%rsp
  45d124:       76 0b                   jbe    45d131 <main.main+0x11>
  45d126:       55                      push   %rbp
  45d127:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  45d12a:       e8 11 00 00 00          callq  45d140 <main.f>
  45d12f:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  45d130:       c3                      retq
  45d131:       e8 ca cd ff ff          callq  459f00 <runtime.morestack_noctxt.abi0>
  45d136:       eb e8                   jmp    45d120 <main.main>
  45d138:       cc                      int3
  45d139:       cc                      int3
  45d13a:       cc                      int3
  45d13b:       cc                      int3
  45d13c:       cc                      int3
  45d13d:       cc                      int3
  45d13e:       cc                      int3
  45d13f:       cc                      int3

000000000045d140 <main.f>:
  45d140:       49 3b 66 10             cmp    0x10(%r14),%rsp
  45d144:       76 21                   jbe    45d167 <main.f+0x27>
  45d146:       55                      push   %rbp
  45d147:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  45d14a:       48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  45d14e:       48 8d 05 2b 5d 00 00    lea    0x5d2b(%rip),%rax        # 462e80 <type:*+0x4e80>
  45d155:       e8 06 ee fa ff          callq  40bf60 <runtime.newobject>
  45d15a:       48 c7 00 04 00 00 00    movq   $0x4,(%rax)
  45d161:       48 83 c4 10             add    $0x10,%rsp
  45d165:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  45d166:       c3                      retq
  45d167:       e8 94 cd ff ff          callq  459f00 <runtime.morestack_noctxt.abi0>
  45d16c:       eb d2                   jmp    45d140 <main.f>

BTW, you can use more "-m" to see more infos output by the compiler, like -gcflags="-m -m -m".
./main.go:7:6: can inline f with cost 15 as: func() *int { y := 2; res := y * 2; return &res }
./main.go:3:6: can inline main with cost 19 as: func() { _ = f() }
./main.go:4:10: inlining call to f
./main.go:4:10: Before inlining:
.   CALLFUNC PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   CALLFUNC-Fun
.   .   NAME-main.f Class:PFUNC Offset:0 Used FUNC-func() *int tc(1) # main.go:7:6
./main.go:4:10: After inlining
.   INLCALL-init
.   .   AS2 Def tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   .   INLMARK # +main.go:4:10
.   INLCALL PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   INLCALL-Body
.   .   AS-init
.   .   .   DCL # main.go:4:10 main.go:8:5
.   .   .   .   NAME-main.y Class:PAUTO Offset:0 InlLocal OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:8:5
.   .   AS Def tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:8:7
.   .   .   NAME-main.y Class:PAUTO Offset:0 InlLocal OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:8:5
.   .   .   LITERAL-2 int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:8:10
.   .   AS-init
.   .   .   DCL # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:5
.   .   .   .   NAME-main.res Class:PAUTO Offset:0 Addrtaken InlLocal OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:5
.   .   AS Def tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:9
.   .   .   NAME-main.res Class:PAUTO Offset:0 Addrtaken InlLocal OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:5
.   .   .   MUL int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:14
.   .   .   .   NAME-main.y Class:PAUTO Offset:0 InlLocal OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:8:5
.   .   .   .   LITERAL-2 int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:16
.   .   BLOCK tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   .   BLOCK-List
.   .   .   DCL tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   .   .   .   NAME-main.~r0 Class:PAUTO Offset:0 InlFormal OnStack PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:7:10
.   .   .   AS2 tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   .   .   AS2-Lhs
.   .   .   .   NAME-main.~r0 Class:PAUTO Offset:0 InlFormal OnStack PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:7:10
.   .   .   AS2-Rhs
.   .   .   .   ADDR PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:10:12
.   .   .   .   .   NAME-main.res Class:PAUTO Offset:0 Addrtaken InlLocal OnStack Used int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:9:5
.   .   .   GOTO main..i0 tc(1) # main.go:4:10
.   .   LABEL main..i0 # main.go:4:10
.   INLCALL-ReturnVars
.   .   NAME-main.~r0 Class:PAUTO Offset:0 InlFormal OnStack PTR-*int tc(1) # main.go:4:10 main.go:7:10

./main.go:4:7:[1] main stmt: _ = ~r0
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt:  :=
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: <node inlmark>
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: y := 2
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: var y int
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: res := y * 2
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: var res int
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: var ~r0 *int; ~r0 = &res; goto .i0
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: var ~r0 *int
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: ~r0 = &res
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: goto .i0
./main.go:4:10:[1] main stmt: .i0:
./main.go:4:10:.i0:  non-looping label
./main.go:8:7:[1] f stmt: y := 2
./main.go:8:5:[1] f stmt: var y int
./main.go:9:9:[1] f stmt: res := y * 2
./main.go:9:5:[1] f stmt: var res int
./main.go:10:5:[1] f stmt: return &res
./main.go:9:5: res escapes to heap:
./main.go:9:5:   flow: ~r0 = &res:
./main.go:9:5:     from &res (address-of) at ./main.go:10:12
./main.go:9:5:     from return &res (return) at ./main.go:10:5
./main.go:9:5: moved to heap: res

